# eclipse luna ctrl+space (content assist) no colored box/background around selection

Tags: eclipse, selection, content-assist, eclipse-luna

there are a lot of questions about content assist in here, but nothing that fits to my problem. I downloaded eclipse luna and I am missing a dotted selection box, around my current selection when I hit `ctrl + space`. I can use my arrow keys as usual to navigate up and down to choose a different suggestion. The dotted selection box appears (or selection background) if I press `tab` after pressing `ctrl + space`.
Hopefully this is not a feature of the new luna release, because this is driving my crazy like hell...
Are there any fixes for this? I don't want to switch back to previous release, because there are a LOT of troubles with the GUI elements in open suse 12.3 / kde.

thx

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. Why is this driving you crazy?

Comment: because I used to only press ctrl + space (for years). additionally pressing tab is making me uncomfortable. this should be an option. I guess I am not the only one. Like we keep saying: a human is an habitual being ;) ... edit: if its not a bug: why is changing of selection working without seeing it?!

Comment: @lifeOfPI Did you find a solution to this? If you did, please add it as an answer and I will vote for it!